# CHECK constrain in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a simple table in MySQL that contain two columns: Timestamp and floats. All I need is to ensure that new inserted value is greater than any other before in table. How can I achive that proper way?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`table1` (
   `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   `read` FLOAT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`timestamp`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_CHECKCONSTRAINT 
BEFORE INSERT ON TABLE1 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
DECLARE msg varchar(255); 
IF NOT new.READ > (SELECT MAX(READ) FROM TABLE1) THEN 
SET msg = 'INVALID DATA' 
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg; 
END IF; 
END
```

Comment: I guess I also need to add `DELIMETER $$` before and `DELIMETER ;` after above code. But I'm still get error: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg; 
END IF; 
END`' at line 8 I'm using `Server version: 5.5.44-0+deb7u1 (Debian)` if it matters...

Comment: It is supported in version 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

Use a BEFORE INSERT trigger. MySQL does not use CHECK constraints.